# How to test @Inject service by provider when it uses a factory using JestJs on Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jestjs, jasmine

I m trying to test a component where I m injecting a specific service declared in the shared module as below.

```
   providers: [
        {
            provide: 'ParameterSelectionService',
            useFactory: () =>
                SharedModule.getSelectionServiceInstance<ParameterModel>(
                    'ParameterModel'
                )
        },
        {
            provide: 'RuleSelectionService',
            useFactory: () =>
                SharedModule.getSelectionServiceInstance<RuleModel>('RuleModel')
        }
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {
    static instances: Map<string, SelectionService<any>> = new Map();

    static getSelectionServiceInstance<T>(keyName: string): T {
        let instance = this.instances.get(keyName);
        if (instance === undefined) {
            instance = new SelectionService<T>();
            this.instances[keyName] = instance;
        }
        return instance as unknown as T;
    }
}
```

In the component I m using the @Inject to specify the provider

```
 constructor(
        @Inject('RuleSelectionService')
        private ruleSelectionService: SelectionService<RuleModel>,
        @Inject('ParameterSelectionService')
        private parameterSelectionService: SelectionService<ParameterModel>, ... )
```

while writting my test I had two instances of the Rules Selection Service so I tried googling how to specify in test what provider to use to inject but didn't found anything ( my search was not giving results I feel like missing keywords ) so I tryied to reverse engeneer the Inject to understand and debug it working, this leaded me to this attempt

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [DiliParametersCategoryComponent],
            imports: [
                CoreModule,
                MaterialModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                SharedModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot()
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

  beforeEach(() => {

        const paramProviderToken : InjectionToken<SelectionService<ParameterModel>>  = new InjectionToken<SelectionService<ParameterModel>>('ParameterSelectionService');
        parameterSelectionService = TestBed.inject<SelectionService<ParameterModel>>(paramProviderToken);
        const ruleServiceProviderToken : InjectionToken<SelectionService<RuleModel>> =  new InjectionToken<SelectionService<RuleModel>>('RuleSelectionService');
        ruleSelectionService = TestBed.inject<SelectionService<RuleModel>>(ruleServiceProviderToken);

    });
```

***However my injection now is undefined*** !!!

What should I do to get the desired service injection on testing using the configuration that I already made on the shared module.

Comment: if you think that this question is hard please add a flag to this comment because I  was thinking this was not meant to be hard to answer

Comment: Why you have created a shared wrapper service instead of directly dealing with service in your component?

Comment: I want to create multiple selection services . That can be shared between multiple components . Knowing I have non related components.

Comment: Instead of managing every selection service and synchronizing selection between every component having one service by model and cdi managed seems to me the best way.

Comment: do you want to create singleton services ?

Comment: I have already implemented a workaround by injecting a factory. However if there is no way to test this case and to simply use DI as I see fit. This will lead me to ask if DI IS WELL ILPLEMENTED ON JEST AND ANGULAR . since I can achieve the same desired result intuitively under spring echosystem

Comment: For my point of view and perspective is more about testing this fonctionality then achieving the completion of my US.

Comment: I don't think you required that wrapper service at all. You should directly inject the service. Having said that you should be able to mock the current implementation as well.